# Mostrar datos de perfil por medio de session PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Hola amigos actualmente estoy tratando de migrar este código de perfil de session a pdo pero me da errores.

La situacion es la siguiente si inicio session y deseo modificar mis datos de perfil pero como ya dije, me muestra error e le hice un `var_dump` y me arroja lo siguiente:

> array(11) { ["idUser"]=> string(2) "12" ["loginUsers"]=> string(9)
>   "userNtest" ["nameProfi"]=> string(8) "Standard" ["idProfile"]=>
>   string(1) "2" ["id"]=> NULL ["correo"]=> NULL ["idnivel"]=> string(13)
>   "Administrador" ["Administrador"]=> string(12) "Yoclens2016-"
>   ["nombres"]=> string(1) " " ["user"]=> NULL ["password"]=> NULL }

Anexo el codigo completo a ver en que esto fallando:

PRIMERO:

archivo para validar las sessiones:

`Preparamos la consulta y la ejecutamos 
    $sql = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user = :user AND 
    password = :password AND idnivel = \'Administrador\'  LIMIT 1');
    $sql->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
    $sql->bindParam(':password', hash('sha256', $_POST['password']));
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->closeCursor();
    // Comprobamos si ha devuelto algun registro
    if($sql->rowCount()){
    // Iniciamos sesion
    session_start();
    // Recuperamos los datos de la consulta 
    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //definimos las variables necesarias para la sesion
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['idnivel'] = 'Administrador';
    $_SESSION['cedula'] = $cedula;
    $_SESSION['nombres'] = $row['nombres'].' ' .$row['apellidos'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['telefono'] = $telefono;
    $_SESSION['direccion'] = $direccion;
    // Redirigimos la pagina 
    header("Location: admin/home.php");
    exit;`

ahora creen que esta bien de como se define las variables necesarias para la sesion? luego de eso ya inicio session ahora una vez ya iniciada la session lo que quiero es cambiar los datos de perfil de ese usuario que tiene la session iniciada, pero no me carga ningun valor los campos los muestra en blanco, este archivo de abalo es para cambiar los datos de perfil del usurio que seria miperfil.php, pero como dije antes solo se me muestran los campos en blanco

```php
    <!-- la session-->

<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['Administrador']))
      {

        header('Location: ../index.php?Error=Acceso denegado');
echo "<script>alert('Disculpe Acceso registringido, Usuario no Autorizado')</script>";

        exit(); 
      }
  ?>

<!-- fin de la session-->



    introducir el código aquí<!-- proceso para consultar-->

<?php

var_dump($_SESSION);



$user=$_SESSION['user'];
$password=$_SESSION['password'];
$perfil = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user = :user AND password = :password");
$perfil->bindParam(':user',$_SESSION['user']);
$perfil->bindParam(':password',$_SESSION['password']);
$perfil->execute();
$editar_linea = $perfil->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);{



?>

<!-- fin proceso para consultar-->

<!-- para mostrar los datos-->
value='<?php echo $editar_linea['cedula'];?>'

<!-- fin para mostrar los datos-->
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: el que esta arriba

Comment: Lo que está arriba es el resultado de hacer `var_dump`, no es ningún error. Por favor, añade más datos: ¿Cómo no funciona el código?¿Se muestra algún error (y dónde)?¿Has probado a poner `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio del código PHP? La contraseña es NULL, ¿afectará eso la consulta?

Comment: como puedo hacer para editar el contenido para poner los codigos bien

Comment: Alvaro Montoro ya la edite

Answer (score 1):

No veo que esten declaradas en ningún lado las variables como por ejemplo `$cedula`.

Si esa información está en el query que ejecutaste más arriba, el código en cada caso debería ser:

```
$_SESSION['cedula'] = $row['cedula'];
```

También, si no estas haciendo más de una query, quitaría el `$sql->closeCursor();`